# How can I convert this RIFF WAVE .bin file?

Tags: audio, vlc-media-player, conversion, wav, hexadecimal

I'm trying to extract some audio from a program, and I've got as far as getting a .bin file. When I open this file with a hex editor, the first line is `RIFF ÷! WAVEfmt 4`.

I've done some research, and there is a similar question on superuser.com, but I tried that user's solution (try to open it in wavepad) and it did not work. I have also used a tool called Dragon Unpacker, but it recognised it as a .wav file and converted it, but it would not open with any audio players apart from VLC, which gave no sound and crashed after 20 seconds.

The sound file is [here](http://www.filedropper.com/00000_6). I am using Windows 7 32 bit if that matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a converter called [at9tools](https://amicitiamods.jcink.net/index.php?showtopic=29) that can convert `.at9` RIFF WAVE files to `.wav`. Running the `.exe` file using cmd will tell you how to use the command `-d` to convert the file. I hope this helps others with this problem.

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on your question.  If you accept your own answer (click the checkmark), that will indicate that you solved the problem.  That makes it easier for other readers to spot proven solutions.

Comment: Where can at9tools be found?