# Need help converting a .wav RIFF WAVEfmt to MP3

Tags: audio, audio-recording, audio-conversion, wav, sound-editing

I have a couple of .wav files from a Palm Pilot or possibly an old Windows Pocket PC that are in the format of a .wav RIFF WAVEfmt file.  I can't play them, and would like to convert them to some modern, playable format.

Programs tried so far with no luck:

- VLC
- Quicktime
- Windows Media Player
- Da Vinci Resolve
- Cool Edit Pro 2.0
- FFMPEG
- Max
- XLD
- Handbrake
- Audacity
- at9tool
- XMedia Recode
- Adobe Audition
- DBPowerAmp Music Converter
- NCH Switch Sound File Converter
- pilot-wave (Linux)
- Goldwave
- SoX / SoXI
- Python libraries: wave, soundfile, scipy.io.wavfile

Here are some details on the file:

- RIFF WAVEfmt
- Encoding:            HP CU
- Num Channels :       1
- Sample Rate:     8000
- Avg Bytes Per Sec:   300
- Bit Rate:            2404
- Codec Tag String:   [25][0][0][0]
- Codec Tag:           0x0019

Raw Header:
52 49 46 46 AC 86 00 00 57 41 56 45 66 6D 74 20 28 00 00 00 19 00 01 00 40 1F 00 00 2C 01 00 00 48 00 00 00 16 00 00 20 0A 00 40 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 64 61 74 61 70 86 00 00 D0 F8 00 12 E9 AD B7 44 48 99 C9 59 13 42 D4 EE 84 29 02 98 61 D7 77 A2 17 69 2B 99 A1 2A 52 D2 35 24 19 38 54 B2 24 9B E1 D2 65 3E 59 73 1E 21 4A 53 A1 42 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

I believe that it is the type of A.18 on this page:
https://www.iana.org/assignments/wave-avi-codec-registry/wave-avi-codec-registry.xhtml

Here is a link to a sample:  https://easyupload.io/nbl0tb

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried ffmpeg?

Comment: I just tried FFMPEG and got:  "unknown codec"

Comment: post one somewhere we can reach it.

Comment: @Tetsujin Great idea.  Here it is:  https://easyupload.io/nbl0tb

Comment: Sorry, tried my three best heavy lifters - Max, XLD & Handbrake - no joy.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thank you for your efforts!

Comment: No worries. Wish you luck :))

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1146087/how-can-i-convert-this-riff-wave-bin-file

Comment: @Moab I just tried the at9tool, but it didn't seem to work.  I may not have been using it correctly though.

Comment: I've always used [dBpoweramp](https://www.dbpoweramp.com/codec-central.htm) for media conversion, and while it is paid software, they do offer a free trial

Comment: @Magwich its all i could find.

Comment: You can add sox/soxi to that list, and the python libraries `wave`, `soundfile`, `scipy.io.wavfile`. All fail with an error indicating that it's an unknown format (`type 19`, `unknown format: 25`, `Error in WAV/W64/RF64 file. Malformed 'fmt ' chunk.`, `Unknown wave file format: CU_CODEC` respectively).

Comment: Perhaps you can [discard the header of the file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55420292/1256347) and then read in the data?

Comment: @Saaru Lindestøkke  Thanks for the info!

Comment: The issue is not the WAV (RIFF WAVE) by itself. RIFF WAV is just an envelope and you can put inside standard PCM data. The issue is the Codec (HP CU) which is likely to be proprietary, then it can be hard to find an adequate decoder. Google HP CU codec doesn’t give me something good : just some table which can be used to identify the codec, but not the codec itself.

Comment: @Frédéric Loyer  That's what I've been finding as well.  Thank you!